# Setting working directory in VSCode 14.6.x when using CMake Tools to something else then build directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Since the update of CMake Tools 1.4.2 ([Incorrect run folder #1395](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1395)) the working directory of the launched binary isn't the workspace directory anymore, but the build directory (due to that files loaded with relative paths are not found anymore).

<del>I tried to figure out in the release notes and the settings if there were some changes that cause that behavior, but I'm not able to find a reason or a solution for that.</del>

The setup is:

- Linux
- VSCode 1.14.1
- CMake Tools 1.4.2

I tried to set the `cwd` using `launch.json`, but I'm not able to get it to work.

My `launch.json` currently looks that way:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know how the working directory can be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For debugging it can be changed with:

```
   "cmake.debugConfig": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

For a regular run/launch it is currently not possible without changing the source of the extension.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're using a multi-root workspace, the `${workspaceFolder:NAME}` functionality does not currently get parsed correctly by the cmake extension (as of v1.4.2).  The related issue seems to suggest the fix is complete however not integrated, for some reason slated past the 1.5 series rather than the next release.